How important is it to avoid a duplicate name?
I am about to publish my first paper in a few months and, as many on this site have already done, I am pondering which name to use. I happen to have multiple surnames, like say Abel Burton Cürtis Zumba. Due to a non-ASCII character in one of these middle names, I was considering just abbreviating everything in the middle and just use Abel B. C. Zumba (I’ve read conflicting positions on diacritics in names, but would rather avoid all the hassles that I can).
The problem is, both my first and last name are relatively common. This means there already exists one “Abel B. Zumba” listed on mathscinet, who just started publishing too. Granted, he publishes in another area from me, but I’m still wondering: is just one extra middle initial enough?
I know the choice of name is very important, and, while not definitive, I really just want to avoid as much of a hassle as I can with author identification (and misidentification), citation tracking, etc…
Also, how important is it to use a name that “bumps you up” the author list? Is there a case to be made for ignoring the “Zumba” and using one of the middle names as last name?
Thanks in advance!

Is it literally the difference between "B. C." and "B."?

I strongly recommend you get an ORCID ID - that will solve many of your issues here, in making sure that your work is correctly attributed to you and not another A.B. Zumba.

@AzorAhai-him- While I obviously used a fake name to illustrate above, yes, it is literally the same first name, middle initial and last name (but different person and no second middle initial)

@WhatTheDuck I do have an ORCID ID, but I just don’t know how Mathscinet uses indexes papers. I am unsure whether ORCID is sufficient to avoid all the trouble

I think you are focusing on the wrong issue here. Anecdotally: I have a letter in name that only exists in two languages in the world and it has not once been a source of problems for me. Unless it offends you if someone occasionally removes your special diacritic, my recommendation is that this isn't worth spending much time on. In contrast, figuring out where the surname starts in a long Spanish or Portuguese name has repeatedly been a headache for me, and I imagine much more so for actual holders of such names. People often do not even know that the whole multiple surname thing exists.

Okay, next question. You have four names. You have said in two places you have multiple surnames and multiple middle names. This can't be true, is Curtis a middle name or last name?

@AzorAhai-him- by surnames, I mean everything. So everything but Abel is a surname, with the two in the middle (AKA, not Zumba) are the two middle names

@AdamPřenosil Can replacing a special letter for an ascii character cause issues with citations, though? And, as for your comment on long names, I understand it to mean just to avoid spelling out middle names fully, is that correct?

At least in the Anglo tradition, which most journals are going to follow, these are mutually exclusive categories. Do your siblings share all three names?

@AzorAhai-him- What I mean is, both in the middle would be considered “middle names” and the last would be considered the “family name”

"Can replacing a special letter for an ascii character cause issues with citations, though?" Like, if someone cites your paper and forgets about your diacritics? No, I would say this is unlikely to cause any issues (but see Buffy's comment on ORCID). "And, as for your comment on long names, I understand it to mean just to avoid spelling out middle names fully, is that correct?" No, I am just saying having diacritics in your name is a non-issue, the real issue you want to give some thought to is the multiple surnames thing. I am not making any recommendations on how to handle this.

@Gauss Gotcha - that's not the same as having multiple "surnames."

For Mathscinet, they make great effort to correctly distinguish authors with the exact same name (you can also link ORCID), and they also identify when the same author publishes under different-looking names).  However other databases do not.  And if there ever is a mistake, you can send them a correction.

This is not an answer to your literal question, but practically have you considered using "Abel Burton Curtis-Zumba" as your name on publications? It seems like this version would solve your issue as long as you're ok with a slight mutilation of your name...

@user2705196 My fear of using an unabbreviated name in full is the aforementioned diacritics and the issue highlighted by Adam Přenosil with long names. Out of curiosity, is there a practical difference between what you propose and “Abel Burton-Curtis Zumba” (i.e. hyphenating the two names in the middle)?

You could potentially drop the Burton and be Abel C. Zumba, which I would guess is less likely to be confused with Abel B. Zumba than Abel B. C. Zumba would be. But of course that depends on whether that would feel right to you. I wouldn't worry too much about the non-ASCII character, although I don't have one in my name so maybe I'm not aware of the problems it might cause.

You could also consider "A. Burton Zumba"

I have friends with 3 middle initials, and they use all of them. One Iranian colleague had more trouble with his two surnames - he now publishes under his 'last last' name and uses an initial for the penultimate name, so he's 'Zumba, ABC'. Not correct, but harder to mess up. I also replaced the special character in mine: 'ss' for 'ß'.

For two people in the same field, having the same name is an inconvenience. For people in different fields it isn't much of an issue. I share a name with another academic in a very different field and so internet searches turn both of us up in results. But no one is confused. Your case is more difficult as you share fields as well as names.
You can (should) also get an ORCID number that distinguishes you from all others. Include it somewhere in your papers, even as a footnote.
In pure math (and some other theoretical fields) choosing a name like Aaron Aardvark to get yourself listed first is tacky and will be recognized by colleagues as such. And in pure math, where alphabetical listing is the "norm", no one will pay attention to author order as representing much other than spelling, but will look to acknowledgement statements when distinguishing contribution is needed.
If such choosing of names became common I anticipate paper with six authors all named Aaron Aardvark.
Note also, that you have limited control over the presentation of your name if you give it several parts or several initials. Publishers and those who maintain databases of scholarly work won't always follow what you write. In particular, Abel Burton Cürtis Zumba is fairly unlikely to be preserved. This is especially problematic for those whose family name is Cürtis Zumba when the database will only accept one word and may choose the wrong one, depending on the culture of the author.
Keep it simple and get an ORCID ID.

You say sharing a name with someone in the field (in this case, mathematics) is an inconvenience. I agree, but one of my doubts is whether having a second middle initial as a differentiator is sufficient to avoid the issues that arise, or whether it would be better to opt for some alternative (say, using a middle name instead of the last name, or using more than one fully written surname)

Again, note that you don't have control over how your name is listed in collections and databases. Whatever you write can be undone by others. If someone has the paper in hand, they probably see your preferred name, but in a search it isn't so straightforward. My spouse's first name is two words. That was fine when she was born, but lots of systems fail in that case.

Obligatory link to Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Names.

My name is tragically common. But I have yet to have my (limited) legal research get too mixed up with the writings by the other Timothy Wiseman in historical journals of . I did frequently receive emails and letters for LTC Wiseman when I was 1LT Wiseman, but that is different and always got straightened out.  In short, I agree, this is a minor inconvenience and solved by something along the lines of an ORCID number.

Ah, but you do have to be slightly careful across fields in very limited scenarios. Consider Michael I. Jordan (statistics) vs Michael Jordan (basketball).

@user176372, hmmm, does Michael Jordan (statistics) have branded basketball shoes? Asking for a friend.

I won't be around for a few days, busy getting my name changed to Aaron Aardvark.

@cag51, Aaron Aanya Aardvark?

An example out of my personal drawer: Pablo A. Ferrari and
Patrik L. Ferrari happen to be widely recognised mathematicians working in closely related subfields of probability and occasionally citing each other. Both authors have ORCID profiles and systematically use their middle names' initials.
Senior experts in the respective subfields know this fact and thoroughly check whom they are citing. Based on the fact that they have the same initials, almost everybody else occasionally confuses the two. Somebody confuses them systematically, somebody identifies them as the same person.
That is to say that homonymy happens even in the same areas, and adding initials is generally not sufficient to be correctly identified.
Personally, I would strongly recommend to:

get an ORCID ID
get an arXiv author identifier
whenever possible (e.g. in the arXiv author field) always specify your affiliation as a further identifier
add initials of, or preferably your full middle names or even the full list of names, cf. this question
claim your preprints and publications via widely indexed scholarly profiles (especially Google scholar), cf. this question
depending on how flexible you are with writing your name, use at least two surnames connected by a hyphen, even if this is not the usual way you would write your surname, as suggested by Azor Ahai in his comment. The hyphen is necessary in order not to incur in other problems (e.g. this and this questions), and gives you more control on how your name will be rendered. (As noted by Buffy, this too is an issue.)
For publishers, repositories and websites, diacritics are not really a serious problem anymore, cf. e.g. this question
be consistent in the choice of your academic name and use the same name, with the same spelling, diacritics and hyphenation consistently for every purpose that is related to academia, including profiles and personal website, slides, abstracts, etc.

None of these suggestions alone will be very effective in preventing misidentification, so it best to combine as many of them as you can and/or are comfortable with.
Finally, in my opinion concerns about changing the order in which your name appears in the author list by choosing to use one of your surnames are a non-issue. Firstly, in mathematics you will probably not have that many coauthors, which makes the relative position of your surname in the author list much less apparent. (Aaron Aardvark will not be competing for first place with Aaron Abart). Secondly, it is your (sur)name (and in some cultures it is already fairly strange to use your last surname rather than your first surname), so just go with that.

I can't give advice about the diacritics issue, but about the other things:

How important is it to avoid a duplicate name?

More important than "not important at all". Setting aside considerations like automated citation tracking, you are mostly dealing with human psychology here, so technocratic solutions like ORCID ID are not going to solve the whole problem. Over the course of your career people will be googling you, trying to remember your name after reading your paper or seeing you speak at a conference or being introduced to you over lunch by a colleague, etc. There will be plenty of occasions where people may be at small but non-negligible risk of mistaking you for someone else if your name is similar (even if not identical) to someone else's name; more so when that person is also in the same discipline as you. The fact that that person works in a different area than you makes this a bit less of an issue, but still not entirely a non-issue.

This means there already exists one “Abel B. Zumba” listed on mathscinet, who just started publishing too. Granted, he publishes in another area from me, but I’m still wondering: is just one extra middle initial enough?

I'd say it's not enough to eliminate the problem of potential confusion between you and the other Zumba. Maybe adding another initial would still not be enough, I'm not sure, but having two initials would probably help.

Also, how important is it to use a name that “bumps you up” the author list?

Not important at all. Mathematicians expect alphabetically ordered author lists and don't infer anything from the ordering on such lists. If you decide to use one of your other names instead of Zumba, doing it to avoid the conflict with the other Zumba may be a good reason to do that, but doing it to affect where you end up on author lists would not be. (By the way, there might be some good reasons to stick with Zumba: "Z" is one of the least common first letters of a last name in Western countries, and I personally find "Zumba" to be a much more distinctive and memorable last name than "Curtis", at least without the diacritic.)

I agree with the general sentiment - probably adding another initial is not enough. Some systems may only take two names - and then both A.[B.]Z. and A.[B.C.]Z. collide, or a system will take B. C. and then initialize it to B.. I deal with something similar in my own name. Depending on how flexible OP wants to be with their name, I would consider publishing as Curtis-Zumba (w/ or w/o the diacritic - no input from me).

I would try to publish under a name as unique as possible because of sites like Google Scholar, where both you and your 'doppelganger' from whatever field might be mushed into one profile.
For one, it's confusing if someone wants to get a quick overview of what you have published (I find it very handy with seminar speakers), and secondly, metrics like Google's h indices are still widely used in academic evaluation, even if everybody claims they don't check them. My name is not common, but I still use my middle initial, just in case.

Sometimes this isn't possible. There is another person with the exact same Given Middle Family combination as me, living in the same city as me. I assume there are probably many others of us throughout the world. Plus, some countries have a handful of different family names that are shared by much of their populations. For example, China has 100 million people named Wang, another 100 million named Li, and another 100 million named Zhang.

Sure, that's why I said 'try' - and the OP seems to have options. We can't single-handedly reform Google Scholar, can we?
